# sizeof() и битовые поля

Tags: c++, структуры, sizeof

Вот имеется структура:

```
struct Data
{
    char A : 4;
    unsigned B: 12;
};
```

Если убрать в ней поле A, то `sizeof(Data)` выдаст 4. Нормально.
Убрать поле B, `sizeof(Data)` вернет 1. Нормально.
А если оставить  A и B, то `sizeof(Data)` вернет 8!. Непонятно.

Почему 8, а не 5?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Низкоуровневые детали размещения в памяти битовых полей не стандартизованы и определяются реализацией.

Однако с абстрактной точки зрения битовые поля выделяются внутри т.наз. *единиц аллокации*. Обычно *единица аллокации* - это просто полноценное поле того самого типа, который указан в объявлении битового поля. Последовательные битовые поля пакуются в последнюю выделенную единицу аллокации, пока она не заполнится.

И в некоторых реализациях смена типа в объявлении битового поля приводит к досрочному завершению заполнения текущей единицы аллокации и выделению новой единицы аллокации. Т.е. в данном случае при работе с такими реализациями в вашем примере получится две отдельные единицы аллокации: типа `char` и типа `unsigned`. В таких реализациях эти единицы аллокации обычно ведут себя так же как и обычные поля соответствующего типа, т.е. фактически вы имеете дело с

```
struct Data
{
    char unit1;
    unsigned unit2;
};
```

А такая структура имеет размер 8 из соображений выравнивания. Если же вы явно запросите выравнивание в 1, то такая структура получит размер 5.

В компиляторе GCC, например, используется совсем другой подход к выделению новых единиц аллокации и там ваша структура получит размер 4.

Answer (score 2):

Если поле имеет размер 12 бит и хочется сэкономить на размере, то совершенно нет смысла делать его типом int, имеющим размер 4 байта. Структуру из примера можно переписать так

```
struct Data {
    uint16_t A : 4;
    uint16_t B : 12;
};
```

Занимает всего два байта.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Более того, размер int не обязан быть 4 байта.